# Writing Huge Chunks of data to NSData objects-iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I've a video file about 2GB in size. This header of video file is encrypted (approximately 528 bytes encrypted). In order to Decrypt this video file i'm reading all bytes from the file  into an NSData object.
As soon as i write this file into NSData object my Application crashes(possibly b'coz max-256MB RAM for iPad).

So how do i go about storing this NSData object into Virtual memory of an iPad/ iPhone temporarily?

Any other approach by means of which i can achieve the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an [`NSInputStream`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to read in the file piece by piece so you aren't loading it all into memory all at once.  Specifically you'll want to make use of [`hasBytesAvailable`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001982-BAJIDAFH) and  [`read:maxLength:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001982-BAJCCBCH).

Something like:

```
NSInputStream *myStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamWithFilAtPath:pathToAbsurdlyLargeFile];
[myStream open];
Byte buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
while ([myStream hasBytesAvailable])
{
   int bytesRead = [myStream read:buffer maxLength:BUFFER_SIZE];
   NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:bytesRead];
   // do other stuff...
}
[myStream close];
```

Note that you may not need to create an NSData object.  You just mentioned you were using it, so I threw it in.

Comment: the [mystream hasBytesAvailable] is always giving NO Bool value.

Comment: The size of the file is around 300MB, the path to the file given is also correct.

Comment: Added the line `[myStream open];` in my answer.  This is criticial for this to work properly.  You will also need to call `[myStream close];` when you are done with the stream.

Comment: @Pranav did this work for you?  If so, I'd appreciate you marking this as the answer.  Otherwise, share more about what's going on.